# Tsung connected users are not shown

Tags: xml, xmpp, ejabberd, tsung

I am trying to make load testing on xmpp ejabberd server using tsung.Every time i run my tsung.xml file no users are connected.
here it's my tsung.xml file

```
[root@chatting-server-test-2 .tsung]# vim tsung.xml
<servers>
  <server host="localhost" port="5222" type="tcp"></server>
</servers>

  <load>
   <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="3" unit="minute">
    <users interarrival="1" unit="second"></users>
   </arrivalphase>
  </load>

<options>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="100"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="userid_max" value="1000"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="mydomain"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="username" value="sf201285427177"></option>
  <option type="ts_jabber" name="passwd" value="abc123"></option>
</options>

  <sessions>
   <session probability="100" name="xmpp-connection" type="ts_jabber">

    <request>
       <jabber type="connect" ack="no_ack"></jabber>
    </request>

    <thinktime value="2"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="authenticate">
      <request> <jabber type="auth_get" ack="no_ack"></jabber> </request>
      <request> <jabber type="auth_set_plain" ack="no_ack"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>

    <thinktime value="30"></thinktime>

    <transaction name="close">
      <request> <jabber type="close" ack="no_ack"></jabber> </request>
    </transaction>

  </session>
</sessions>
</tsung>
```

when i run the command **ejabberdctl connected_users_number** the connected users are always zero.Can someone figure out what's wrong in the xml file? thanks in advance

Comment: How do you simulate connection?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question. I run the script using the command "tsung start". When I open the ejabberd log files, I find there are incoming accepted connections, but the number of online users never increase.

Comment: Did you tried connect yourself using jabber client?

Comment: yes i try it using a program named spark and i found the user online on the server

Comment: Can you activate logging? What command  connected-users-info returns?

Comment: I figured out the problem there was a problem with the authentication i changed it to SSAL authentication and it works

Comment: Good. Maybe you add your solution as answer so people can enjoy it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem there was a problem with the authentication i changed it **to SSAL authentication** and it works